# Replace those string without the leading/ending whitespace in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I am trying to replace those string without the leading or ending whitespace. But the problem is that `str_detect()` can affect those string in the group as well. Is there a way that I can just replace those string without the leading/ending whitespace?

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  rowid brand     
  <int> <chr>     
1     1 apple     
2     2 Apple     
3     3 apple cafe
4     4 Apple cafe
```

dput:

```
structure(list(rowid = 1:4, brand = c("apple", "Apple", 
"apple cafe", "Apple cafe")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my working script:

```
df %>%
  mutate(brand = case_when(
    str_detect(brand, "apple") ~ "Orange",
    TRUE ~ brand)) %>%   
  group_by(brand) %>% 
  tally()
```

Expected output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  rowid brand     
  <int> <chr>     
1     1 Orange     
2     2 Orange     
3     3 Apple cafe
4     4 Apple cafe
```

Comment: Do you want to match the entire string? `"^apple$"`?

Comment: No string in your data has leading/ending whitespace.

Comment: I mean I don't want to touch "Apple cafe" because the "Apple" has a whitespace behind. I only want to touch the "Apple" in isolation. @RonakShah

Comment: I guess it could work if I make it "^apple$|^Apple$". I just thought there might be a way I could target the string on their attachment to whitespace. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the entire word no need to use regex :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(brand = case_when(tolower(brand) == 'apple' ~ "Orange",
                            TRUE ~ brand))

#  rowid brand     
#  <int> <chr>     
#1     1 Orange    
#2     2 Orange    
#3     3 apple cafe
#4     4 Apple cafe
```

Or in base R :

```
df$brand[tolower(df$brand) == 'apple'] <- 'Orange'
```

Comment: I have to say this make things easier - without the regex or str_detect().